# XCODE: coreplot - Labels fixing

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

I have a case where there is a scroll view for the graph in core-plot. On scrolling to the right, the labels of the y-axis is hidden. Is there a way to fix it visible throughout the scrolling session of the graph?

Answer (score 0):

If your graph hosting view is inside a scroll view, there isn't anything you can do. If you're using the built-in scrolling, set the `axisConstraints` on the y-axis to pin it to the left or right side.